# Does California English have an additional vowel phoneme?

Tags: english, phonology, vowels, phonemes, american-english

I've noticed that my pronunciation of the word *only* differs from the General American pronunciation (I'm from coastal California). This is the pronunciation of *only* that I assume is General American: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/File:En-us-only.ogg.

My pronunciation and that of my friends and family is something like [ˈɔn.li] or [ˈon.li].

At first I thought that the first vowel was probably an allophone of /oʊ/, but then I thought how my pronunciation of *own* is [oʊn], which I think would make a near-minimal pair for the words *only* and *own* in my variety of English.

Additionally, my pronunciations of *lone* and *lonely* are [loʊn] and [ˈloʊn.li] respectively.

If my observations were typical of most English speakers from urban, coastal California, would that mean my variety of English has an additional vowel phoneme (perhaps /ɔ/ or /o/) compared to General American English that has the cot-caught merger?

Comment: In General American, the words _only_, _old_ and _own_ **all** have the same vowel /oʊ/, so referring to _old_ as a way to describe how your pronunciation differs from _own_ is rather ambiguous. American in general doesn’t have short [ɔ] or monophthongal [o] at all, so if that is indeed what you have here, it could be an extra phoneme. How do you pronounce _soul_ (or _sole_), _[a]lone_ and _lonely_? Do those have your _only_ vowel or your _own_ vowel? Do _lone_ and _lonely_ have different vowels? If so, it might be an allophone conditioned by a following /l/ (but only within the same word).

Comment: Do you use the [ˈɔn.li] / [ˈon.li] pronunciation only in connected speech, or also when pronouncing the word on its own? I think I know the pronunciation you're describing, and if so it strikes me as a case of allegro-speech vowel reduction.

Comment: Do you pronounce *own* the same way a General American speaker would?  I speak PNW English (if there is such a thing) and for me the vowel is maybe closer to [əʊ], which is a trait borrowed from California English.  This does not seem to be the same vowel as in the word *only*.  But I do agree that my vowel in *only* does not seem to be [oʊ], nor any diphthong.  To address Janus Bahs Jacquet's question, I pronounce *soul* with a different vowel than *alone*, or *own*.  Harder to tell with *lonely*; that one might be the same as *old/soul/only*.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Thank you, I edited the post to remove the ambiguity. I pronounce *soul* with the vowel quality of *only*. I pronounce *lone* and the first syllable of *lonely* with the vowel of *own*. I'm going to edit my post to include your example of *lone* and *lonely* since I think it's really useful.

Comment: @TKR I pronounce it that way both in connected speech and when pronouncing the word on its own.

Comment: @Juhasz I used [oʊ] in my post for the *own* diphthong, but my pronunciation of the diphthong does seem to start with something like a schwa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably analyzable as /ol/ (the vowel of "goat" + the consonant /l/) but maybe it has the status of a new phoneme for you. As hinted by the comments, for a number of American English speakers the *goat* and *face* vowels /o/, /e/ have different allophones before /l/, /r/ compared to the falling diphthongs that are used elsewhere (giving a pattern that could potentially be loosely transcribed as *bone* /bon/ [boʊ̯n], *bowl* /bol/ [bol]~[boə̯ɫ], *bane* /ben/ [beɪ̯n], *bear* /ber/ [beɚ̯]; obviously, these phonetic and phonemic transcriptions do not cover all accents of American English.)

If you can't make a distinction between your pronunciation of *only* and the pronunciation of a hypothetical form "olnly", then it seems best analyzed as /ol/.

I have seen a number of reports from American English speakers who say that they use some special vowel sound, normally found only before /l/, in some words where it is not followed by the letter "L", such as "only" or "both". As far as I know, this is not a fixed feature of any particular variety or region, nor does it affect a fixed list of words. [Here's a speaker reporting "olnly" on Reddit.](https://www.reddit.com/r/NoStupidQuestions/comments/n0i6vj/) [Here's a speaker reporting "bolth" on Stack Exchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/600809).

I don't think the *cot-caught* merger has much to do with this.

Comment: I wonder how related this is to the HOLY-WHOLLY split ("GOAT split") of London and Australian English.